# 2010 Ford Taurus keypad panel pulling away

Tags: ford, door

I just bought the car and in process of discussing the issue I have with the door keypad panel pulling away. The dealer promised to get a garage(close to my house) to fix it for me but I'd like to know how this can be also fixed. Just for my information so I don't get screwed over or something.

I found this [forum](http://www.taurusclub.com/forum/119-5th-6th-gen-aesthetics-interior-wheels-tires/278618-2010-sel-driver-s-side-keypad-panel-pulling-away.html) where a person have similar issue and suggestion using glue/adhesives which sounds too easy or kind of unprofessional to me. But I'm not sure since this is a new car to me. Just using glue feels to me not enough but I have no experience with this brand.

How is this panel attached to the door?

Here are the pics of the problem:
[image: The driver's side keypad pulling away]

it should be
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If adhesive was used by Ford in the first place, I would say that is fine.  I'm not sure what is original, so this isn't a great answer, but it felt like more than a comment.

I had a trim piece repaired by a body shop and they used glue, but the OEM solution was plastic clips (that they had broken...).  The glue failed after a year, and I had to go back and make them repair it properly with a new part. The glue might have worked in the short term, but there was a reason that VW (my car) didn't use glue and opted for clips instead.  For that part, it wasn't going to last 10-15 years.

My point is, Ford has already researched and developed what should be the *right* way to do this, so make sure whatever shop does the work follows their recommendations.

Comment: well, I don't know if an adhesive was used in the first place. Thanks for your comment anyway.